# Is this possible with html & css

Tags: css, html

can this be done? If so what way would you take to accomplish it.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes it can be achieved with HTML and CSS

Comment: @AndrewH im trying to get that multicolor border

Comment: Search google "Gradient CSS", there are a lot of css gradient generators which make it easy to make gradients.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1eefc8wo/

Answer (score 1):

This is great online tool to create CSS gradients and use generated code on your design: [www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)